# ReadMsgQueue Return value

Tags: c++, winapi, while-loop, queue

I am using a MsgQueue to send a structure from one process to another. To read the message queue, im using a `while` loop that checks the return value of the `ReadMsgQueue()`. According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909162.aspx), `ReadMsgQueue()`
returns **TRUE** to indicate success and **FALSE** to indicate failure. Going off of this information, i wrote the following loop:

```
while(MsgQueueCommunicator::getInstance()->b_MsgQueueCommunicator_Read_MessageQueue(m_hMsgQAlarmState,alarm_params))
{
    RETAILMSG(1,(_T("Update_ActiveAlarmList->alarm_params.i32_Alarm_Output: %d"), alarm_params.i32_Alarm_Output));
    RETAILMSG(1,(_T("Update_ActiveAlarmList->alarm_params.i32AlarmType: %d"), alarm_params.i32AlarmType));
    if(alarm_params.b_IsEnable == true)
    {
        RETAILMSG(1,(_T("Update_ActiveAlarmList->alarm_params = true")));
    }
    else
    {
        RETAILMSG(1,(_T("Update_ActiveAlarmList->alarm_params = false")));
    }

}
RETAILMSG(1,(_T("END OF MSGQUEUE WHILE LOOP")));
```

So im just reading the structure and checking the values using `RETAILMSG()`. What i see though is that i never leave the while loop, even though i have stopped writing to the queue. I checked this by adding a retailmsg after the loop and i never saw it get printed out and at the same time, my retail messages inside the while loop also stopped, indicating that there was nothing else to read in the queue.

Should the while loop exit once the queue has been emptied, or am I misunderstanding the return value of `ReadMsgQueue()`?

**EDIT:**
Here is the declaration for `b_MsgQueueCommunicator_Read_MessageQueue()`:

```
BOOL MsgQueueCommunicator::b_MsgQueueCommunicator_Read_MessageQueue(HANDLE hq,AlarmParams& Byte_Flag)
{
    uint32_t dwBytesRead;
    uint32_t dwFlags;
    return ReadMsgQueue(hq,(LPVOID)&Byte_Flag, sizeof(AlarmParams), &dwBytesRead,INFINITE,&dwFlags);
}
```

Comment: Hard to see what else you expected to happen, an empty queue is enitrely normal and not a failure.  Maybe you don't actually like INFINITE.

Comment: @HansPassant What i expected to happen was for `ReadMsgQueue()` to return false if there was nothing else in the queue. However, this does not seem to be the case from the above piece of code, but i am just trying to get verification on whether this is the right conclusion.

Comment: You already know the answer.  The *dwTimeout* argument is there for a good reason.

Comment: ^^ if you want to waste CPU cycles and memory bandwidth on polling an empty queue, set the timeout to 0.

Comment: @MartinJames Instead of doing that, can i check if the status of a queue is changed, i.e. if the read operation is being blocked? That way if there is no data in the queue, i can exit out of the while loop? Since `timeout = 0` isnt a very good solution in my case..

Comment: It sounds like `timeout = 0` is exactly what you want.

Comment: `ReadMsgQueue()`with timeout set to `INFINITE` blocks until data is available or the state of the queue changes. An empty queue is not a state change. Perhaps you should close the queue from the other process, I expect that `ReadMsgQueue()`will return `FALSE`then.